# Deliver a dapp to a client, how to set as owner?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, wallets

So, as a freelancer that wants to make a smart contract for a client, how do you set such client as the owner of the contract?

Would it be setting the owner variable to the eth address of the client, instead of msg.sender, when creating the contract?

Comment: Your client should be the one deploying the contract with his/her private key. So you can add a page in your app for deploying a contract, and then your client can use that page in order to deploy the contract with his/her private key.

Comment: A page in my app? A web page?

Comment: Whatever. This advice covers the ethereum-related part of your question. For strictly web-related issues, you can post the rest of your question on stack overflow.

Comment: You deploy an app with truffle, I still don't see how a client can do it without being technically savvy. Thanks anyways!